# array return index from another array

Tags: javascript

suppose we have this two array. in some condition, I want to return the index of a second array.

```
let a = [1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11 , 12]
let b = [0, 1, 2, 3 , 4 , 5, 6 , 7 , 8, 9, 10, 11]

if (a[2]) ? return b[2] : return null
```

why I need this? because I have a month number of the year that starts from 0 to 11. but I need to turn this 1 12 for storing in my database.
sry about the title of this question if someone has a better title I would be glad about changing it.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Can you please [edit] your question and add the expected output?

Comment: Why not just add 1 to the month in 0-11 format?

Comment: cuase this I have a loop that generate this for 10 years

Comment: What does the duration have to do with anything? If you are just getting the month from 1 you literally just do b[i] + 1. Doesn't matter how many years its for?

Comment: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Like the people above me, i can't see why you just can't add +1. Also it sound like you are trying some stuff with Date, have a look at moment.js, it has this stuff built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the value by adding `11` and get the remainder value with `12`.

```js
function getZeroBasedMonth(n) {
    return (n + 11) % 12;
}

console.log(getZeroBasedMonth(1));
console.log(getZeroBasedMonth(12));
```

For the getting the opposite, just add one.

```js
function getMonth(n) {
    return n + 1;
}

console.log(getMonth(0));
console.log(getMonth(11));
```

Comment: tnx but I need the opposite of this condition , sry if im not clear about that. console.log(getZeroBasedMonth(0)) >>> 1 and console.log(getZeroBasedMonth(11)) >>> 12

Answer (score 0):

Why make this harder than it needs to be? Just add 1 to the value you get from your initial array. Here is, per your comment, 10 years worth of values for the months with a +1 value.

```js
let years = 10;
let months = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
let allYears = [];

for(let i = 0; i < years; i++){
    let year = [];
    for(let x = 0; x < months.length; x++){
        year[x] = months[x] + 1;
    }
    allYears.push(year);
}

console.log(allYears);
```

Comment: if you decide to go down this path, Javascript has a map function for this. There is no need to di it with for loops.